# detect space between two divs and break content to another line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am making a custom template in which i have two divs and both have title . 
I wanted to detect if there is less then 15px left between two divs then break the content into another line for both divs . Is this possible ? I have made a fiddle with css and html

```css
#content .title
{
display:inline-block;
float:left;
text-align:left;
}
#content .sub-title {
display:inline-block;
float:right;
text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="full">
    <div class="full">
      <div class="title">
        <h2><a href="#">Roberts Roberts &amp; Patrirty Smith</a></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-title"><h2>THE EXAMPLE ON THE FLY</h2></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the elements you can do this with CSS media queries:

```css
*
{ 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#content .title
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    border: solid 1px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 400px;
}
#content .sub-title
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 400px;
}
@media (max-width: 815px)
{
    #content .sub-title
    {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="full">
    <div class="full">
        <div class="title">
            <h2><a href="#">Roberts Roberts &amp; Patrirty Smith</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-title"><h2>THE EXAMPLE ON THE FLY</h2></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer . The problem is its a responsive design . But its not full width the main container is max 960px .

Comment: That shouldn't matter as long as you know the widths of things. Can you use media queries to reduce the width and font size of the elements slightly as the viewport width is reduced?

Comment: Yes i can . I am trying this . Ill revert back :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a little Bootstrap with your custom CSS.
Have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/y2dpfeuu/4/)**, I have two options for you to test.

In the Result Fiddle window, try resizing the frame on the left side to see how it works.

When using the Bootstrap cdn link please make sure you place the link above your custom CSS, so that your css has priority.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" >    <div class="container col-xs-12 block">


<div class="block-first bg-info col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
Roberts Roberts &amp; Patrirty Smith
</div> 

<div class="block-second bg-success col-lg-4 col-lg-push-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-md-push-1 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-push-1 col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-push-0">
THE EXAMPLE ON THE FLY
</div> 
</div> 

<div class="container col-xs-12 bg-primary space-around"><br></div>

<div class="container col-xs-12 block">    
<div class="block-first2 bg-primary col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
Roberts Roberts &amp; Patrirty Smith
</div> 

<div class="block-second bg-danger col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
THE EXAMPLE ON THE FLY
</div> 
</div>
```